# Why does Salesforce forbid to have Lightning inside of a frame of Visualforce Page?

Tags: visualforce, lightning

Why does Salesforce forbid to have Lightning inside of a frame of Visualforce Page?
Is there any reason for that?
Is there a way or a hack to overcome this?

I would like to have a lightning app inside of a iframe of a Visualforce page like this

```
<apex:page >
    <iframe src="../c/Lightning.app"/>
</apex:page>
```

and I want to avoid error

```
Refused to display 'https://custom--domain.lightning.force.com/c/Lightning.app' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because lightning apps are not meant to be use on iframes. If you want to use lightning components on visualforce, you need to take a look at [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm)

First your app need to be globally accessible, extend `ltng:outApp` and create a dependency for the components it uses.

```html
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp"> 
    <aura:dependency resource="ui:button"/>
</aura:application>
```

Then you can call it on the visualforce page using the code bellow:

```html
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning />

    <div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:lcvfTest", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("ui:button",
          { label : "Press Me!" },
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
            // do some stuff
          });
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```